# Cannot load iconv in node.js inbox module

Tags: node.js, windows-7, iconv

I've been doing some node.js development on Ubuntu 12.04 recently, but a bug in Ubuntu's openssl combined with the ridiculously bad battery life it affords my Zenbook, I've decided to boot Windows 7 again as my main OS.  I checked my code in before shutting down Linux, and pushed everything to github.  I cloned my github repo on Windows, ran 'npm install' with no errors, and then tried to run my app, but I get this error:

```
> node.js:201
>         throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
>               ^ Error: unknown error
>     at Object..node (module.js:472:11)
>     at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
>     at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
>     at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
>     at require (module.js:370:17)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jared\Documents\GitHub\LoopMe\node_modules\inbox\node_modules\mimelib\mime-functions.js:1:75)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
>     at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
>     at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
```

Line 1 of mime-functions.js is: var Iconv = require("iconv").Iconv;

Comment: Quoted from the iconv [README](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv/blob/master/README.md) "node-iconv may or may not work on Windows. Please try it and report any issues you have."

Comment: Thanks.  Don't know how I missed that one.  I'm starting to see the downside of using a newish technology like node.  I can't run our app on Ubuntu because of a problem with OpenSSL, and I can't run it on Windows because of the incompatibility with iconv.